# Was vigilantism done in fit of anger?

Tags: fiqh, hudud, usool-ul-fiqh

Report 1: Jewish woman under treaty was killed, prophet asked for killer to show up, subsequently it was informed that she reviled the prophet. The prophet condoned blood money and excused the killer.

Report 2: umar bin al khattab executed a hypocrite immediately. When a hypocrite was not happy with the decision of prophet

Do the two incidents differ? Was vigilantism based on instinct or fit of anger?

Incident references: https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/103739

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. The blood of a blasphemer or apostate is rendered lawful to shed. There is no qisas, no blood money and no kaffarah for killing them because these only applies on killing someone whose blood is sacred.

Comment: Ruler carries out this execution through his deployed representative, if a lay Muslim carries out this act without sanction of ruler, is this not considered violation of authority?

Comment: Even if it is a violation of authority that would earn a minor reprimand or punishment under Ta'zir at the discretion of the ruler - it would not call for capital punishment or blood money since those are the recompense of killing someone who is innocent and protected by Islamic law.

Comment: Question edited, sincere gratitude for considering to write comments. Hopefully it's clear now